# How can I create/instantiate an object from an if-else statement?

Tags: java, class, object, inheritance, if-statement

For some reason the following code won't work when trying to create a object from different subclasses based on the result of an if-else statement:

```
if (option == 1) {

     UndergradTA student = new UndergradTA();
     student.setIsUnderGrad(true);

} else if (option == 2) {

     GradTA student = new GradTA();
     student.setIsGrad(true);
}
```

When I then try to use methods on the "student" class later on in the main method it won't allow me, saying "student cannot be resolved".

Comment: Read: [Variable Scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change Your Code to:

```
UndergradTA student = null;
GradTA stud = null;

if (option == 1) {

    student = new UndergradTA();
    student.setIsUnderGrad(true);

} else if (option == 2) {

    stud = new GradTA();
    stud.setIsGrad(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok but now let's say I want to call the objects into a bunch of methods, and I want to do the same for either object that gets created, I have to call the methods for UndergradTA student and GradTA stud seperately?

Comment: if(student!=null){student.callyourmethods()}    if(stud!=null){stud.callyourmethods()}

Answer (score 2):

`student` variable is declared within the scope of the `if/else`, not outside, thus you cannot use it outside these blocks of code.

If `UndergradTA` and `GradTA` have a common super class or interface, then declare the variable outside and use it accordingly:

```
Student student = null;
if (option==1) {
    student = new UndergradTA();
    //cumbersome
    student.setIsUnderGrad(true);
} else if(option==2) {
    student = new GradTA();
    //cumbersome
    student.setIsGrad(true);
}
student.someMEthod(...);
```

Comment: Would replacing the if-else statement with a switch statement fix this, or would it still be only in the scope of the switch statement?

Comment: @RameenRastan it will depend, again, the place where you define the variable. Using a switch could make your code more readable.

Comment: @RameenRastan The second. Also, why do you need to explicitly set a boolean flag when the object type should be enough to determine if a `Student` is undergrad or gradta?